# line break in content of tippy js

Tags: reactjs, web, web-deployment, tippyjs

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import './styles/Register.css'
import axios from "axios";
import Tippy from '@tippyjs/react';
import 'tippy.js/dist/tippy.css'
```

I am using tippy js in my react app. I want to add a line break after `min length 8` and after `must include`.

This the code:

```
<Tippy placement="bottom" content="Min length 8, must incude 1 Uppercase, 1 Lowercase & 1 number">
    <input className="form-control" id="password" name="password" value={user.password} type="password" placeholder="Password" onChange={handleChange}></input>
</Tippy>
```

[image]

Comment: Your `content` can be jsx, so I assume `content={<><div>sentence1</div><div>sentence2</div></>}` would work (or even with a basic `<br />`)

Answer (score 0):

You can pass an array to the `content` of `Tippy`, where each line is a string in the array and have a `<br />` tag as another element between the lines every time you want to have a line break.

```
<Tippy placement="bottom" content={['Min length 8,', <br />, 'must include', <br />, '1 Uppercase, 1 Lowercase & 1 number']}>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example of how to add multiple lines to a tooltip.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Tooltip } from 'react-tippy';
import 'react-tippy/dist/tippy.css';
import MyComponent from './MyComponent';

const ComponentWithTooltip = ({ stringArray }) => {
    const myTooltip = stringArray ? (
        <>
            {stringArray.map((s) => (
                <>
                    <span style={{ textAlign: 'left', display: 'block' }}>{s}</span>
                </>
            ))}
        </>
    ) : (
        null
    );

    return (
        <Tooltip html={myTooltip}>
            <MyComponent />
        </Tooltip>
    );
}

export default ComponentWithTooltip;
```

Comment: As with much to do with styling, there are many correct ways to do this, depending on which libraries and frameworks your app uses. This example can be made more reusable by using children instead of calling `<MyComponent />` inside the tooltip wrapper component.

Answer (score -1):

A simple answer to this question is to use fragments and a line break tag in your content prop.

Your opening tag should then look like this.

```
<Tippy placement="bottom" content={<>Min length 8, must incude</><br /><>1 Uppercase, 1 Lowercase & 1 number</>}>
```